# Implementing Firebase in Play Framework

Tags: android, firebase, playframework, server

We have to implement an android app with a server using the Play Framework and we have to use firebase for server-to-client communication. On the client-side we've implemented firebase successfully(I hope so at least). However, we don't know how to implement firebase messaging on the server-side and the firebase documentation doesn't really help us.

We are using the newest version of Play.

It would be great if someone could explain the implementation process to us.

Answer (score 2):

I have gotten really close to fully implementing firebase on Java Play! I followed the steps here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

1) I manually added the Firebase jars using jar-download(dot)com/online-maven-download-tool.php. I did it manually because the build.sbt was not downloading the jars.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
  <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

2) Get a service account JSON from console. firebase.google.com/

3) Add the code to a singleton in your play project

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
  .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json"))
  .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
  .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

4) Retrieve Data

```
public static class Post {

    public String author;
    public String title;

    public Post(String author, String title) {
        // ...
    }

}

// Get a reference to our posts
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("server/saving-data/fireblog/posts");

// Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        System.out.println(post);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
    }
});
```

This is as far as I have gotten. I am able to retrieve data only once and then the rest of the calls just hang and never return or error out. If you have any more success please comment on this question or my question. [Firebase and Java Play! Framework not fully working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690192/firebase-and-java-play-framework-not-fully-working-together)